# CURL command to C# code Dropbox API

Tags: c#, curl, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox APIs to upload a file to dropbox cloud. I have the access token and I need to execute the following curl command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer NBNBNSBJHDKHDKJJGGD" https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/ -T "C:\Tm\dd.jpg"
```

Could someone please let me know how to do the above in C#

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your support. This got resolved. I feel this will be definitely useful for some one.

```
  string filePath="C:\\Tim\\sundar.jpg";
    RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/");
    IRestRequest request = new RestRequest("files_put/auto/{path}", Method.PUT);
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    long fileLength = fileInfo.Length;
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer FTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXisqFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileLength.ToString());
    request.AddUrlSegment("path", string.Format("Public/{0}", fileInfo.Name));
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    var body = new Parameter
    {
        Name = "file",
        Value = data,
        Type = ParameterType.RequestBody,
    };
    request.Parameters.Add(body);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```